# Elasticsearch 6.3.2 - how to search part-words using all fields on this index?

Tags: elasticsearch, search, search-engine, elasticsearch-6

1. Do you have any idea for create search request? multi-match + part words searching.

```html
 {
      "shop_index": {
          "settings": {
              "index": {
                  "number_of_shards": "5",
                  "provided_name": "shop_index",
                  "creation_date": "1534235625279",
                  "analysis": {
                      "filter": {
                          "nGram_filter": {
                              "token_chars": [
                                  "letter",
                                  "digit",
                                  "punctuation",
                                  "symbol"
                              ],
                              "min_gram": "2",
                              "type": "nGram",
                              "max_gram": "20"
                          }
                      },
                      "analyzer": {
                          "nGram_analyzer": {
                              "filter": [
                                  "lowercase",
                                  "asciifolding",
                                  "nGram_filter"
                              ],
                              "type": "custom",
                              "tokenizer": "whitespace"
                          },
                          "whitespace_analyzer": {
                              "filter": [
                                  "lowercase",
                                  "asciifolding"
                              ],
                              "type": "custom",
                              "tokenizer": "whitespace"
                          }
                      }
                  },
                  "number_of_replicas": "1",
                  "uuid": "SBB9u344RVGm1QQUo-rVMg",
                  "version": {
                      "created": "6030299"
                  }
              }
          }
      }
    }
```

1. mapping

```html
{
      "shop_index": {
          "mappings": {
              "products": {
                  "properties": {
                      "html_keywords": {
                          "type": "text"
                      },
                      "html_title": {
                          "type": "text"
                      },
                      "name": {
                          "type": "text"
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
      }
    }
```

2. I would want to search phrase like -> searching "HOUSE"

   - typing -> "ho" -> show me "HOUSE"
   - typing -> "hou" -> show me "HOUSE"
   - typing -> "use" -> show me "HOUSE
   - typing -> "se"  -> show me "HOUSE"

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using Fuzzy query - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html. Also  consider combining it with slop (how far apart terms are allowed) and use multi_match to search in multiple fields.

Sample query:

```
{
    "query":
    {
        "multi_match":
        {
            "fields": ["field1", "field2"],
            "query": "hous",
            "slop": 3,
            "fuzziness": "AUTO"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, but it doesn't work for me, it looks for only whole words from indexed fileds

Comment: Fuzziness is primarily for addressing spelling mistakes and you can try to tweak it by changing "AUTO" to a number based on your requirement. More details are available here - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#fuzziness. Also have a look at completion suggester and check whether that suits your needs - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html